# How to add numbers like 1, 2, etc. in a ListView?

Tags: android

Here is my code to insert integers in a ListView, but I'm getting a blank screen when I run it.
I am adding the numbers without using string arrays in xml.

How to solve it?

```
ListView lvNumbers;String numbers[]=new String[50];
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

lvNumbers= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNumbers);

for(int i=1;i<=50;i++){numbers[i-1]=String.valueOf(i);}

ArrayAdapter<String> a=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.
simple_list_item_1,numbers);
```

Comment: missing setAdapter

Comment: this is to add nos in listview

Comment: ya got that thanks will Arraadaptor accepts any numbers ie wrapper class arrays also

Answer (score 1):

```
ListView lvNumbers;String numbers[]=new String[50];
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

lvNumbers= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNumbers);

for(int i=1;i<=50;i++){numbers[i-1]=String.valueOf(i);}

ArrayAdapter<String> a=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.
simple_list_item_1,numbers);


//you forgot this line in your code
lvNumbers.setAdapter(a);
```